# issues when trying to make indices unique in xts

Tags: r, xts

I have the following xts object:

```
options("digits.secs" = 1)
ex <- structure(c(NA, -63L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("V2", "V3", "V4")), index = structure(c(1366088402.46, 
1366088402.46, 1366088402.463, 1366088402.463, 1366088469.697, 
1366088469.697), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
ex <- make.index.unique(ex, drop = TRUE, fromLast = TRUE)
```

However, the resulting xts object doesn't have unique indices.  I've also tried using `strptime` with `format="...%OS1"`, which returns `NA` for all values.  The above code intuitively doesn't make sense to me because I'm using output options to try and truncate my dates.

I've searched how other people are handling fractional timestamps, and most results seem to be consistent with the above.  Why isn't `%OS1` working for me, and is `options` really the correct way to handle this?  I want my time index to internally be truncated at specified increments, my index shouldn't change every time I set `options("digits.secs")` to something new.

```
> options("digits.secs"=3)
> head(ex)
                         V2 V3 V4
2013-04-16 00:00:02.460  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:00:02.460 -63  0  1
2013-04-16 00:00:02.463  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:00:02.463  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.697  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.697  NA NA NA
> ex <- align.time(ex, n = 0.1)
> head(ex)
                       V2 V3 V4
2013-04-16 00:00:02.5  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:00:02.5 -63  0  1
2013-04-16 00:00:02.5  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:00:02.5  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.7  NA NA NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.7  NA NA NA
> ex <- make.index.unique(ex, drop = TRUE, fromLast = TRUE)
> head(ex)
                         V2     V3   V4
2013-04-16 00:00:02.5    NA     NA   NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.7    NA     NA   NA
2013-04-16 00:01:09.7 -65.5  -7500 0.25
2013-04-16 00:01:13.5 -64.0  -7500 0.25
2013-04-16 00:01:15.4 -64.0 -10000 0.20
2013-04-16 00:01:24.9 -64.0 -10000 0.20
```

As you can see my data is getting cut down to about a third in length, but even in the first few rows there is a repeated time index at 00:01:09.7.

Comment: What is letting you know that the resulting index is not unique? Are you printing them out and visually comparing, are you using `anyDuplicated(.)`, `length(unique(.))`.  What does your data look like?  If you've found other issues that relate, is it worth linking to them?

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(head(data))` to your question.

Comment: Does this help? http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/11494/focus=11496

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't help because I'm not trying to append fractional digits to create higher resolution timestamps.  My data is timestamped to the nearest nano and I'm trying to give up resolution here, for now all I want is to the 1/10th of a second just to confirm that I can get unique timestamps.  Ricardo, I have printed to console and visually detected non-unique indices, but anyDuplicated(index(data)) returns 0 and length(unique(index(data) == length(index(data)).  My data is all numeric, thank you both for your help thus far.

Comment: Another way I can see that I have non-unique timestamps is that I'm looking at 5.5 hours worth of data right now which is regularly spaced by increments of 0.1 seconds, so I should have:
5.5 * 60 * 60 * 10 = 198,000 rows, and instead I have 203,260.  Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: `options("digits.secs")` doesn't change the index values. It only changes how they're displayed. `make.index.unique(..., drop=TRUE)` will only remove rows that have exactly the same index value. It seems you want to aggregate your data into 0.1 second increments, but it's hard to be sure because you do not provide a reproducible example of your object, your current output, and your expected output.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, I want to actually change my index values and not just change the display.  Is this possible?  strptime is giving me "NA" when I use %OSn with n ranging from 1 to 6, it also might help to note that I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your example is still not reproducible.  `dput(head(data))` already looks like your expected output... and you obviously manually pasted another line in the output of `head(data)` because `head` doesn't print 7 lines by default.

Comment: I tried coming up with a reproducible example, and using align.time I get the desired result from the simplified example but not in my actual data.  I manually added a line before because there were no repeats in the first 6 lines, and I thought it would be equivalent to scrolling further down and finding an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your format like this:

```
strptime(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The 'format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"'output is NA:

```
strptime(Sys.time(), format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you actually want to aggregate your data, not just make the index values unique.  This will work, assuming you want to sum each column.  If you don't want to do that, just substitute another function that does what you want to each column.

```
library(xts)
ex <- structure(c(NA, -63L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("V2", "V3", "V4")), index = structure(c(1366088402.46, 
1366088402.46, 1366088402.463, 1366088402.463, 1366088469.697, 
1366088469.697), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")

options(digits.secs=6)

# endpoints() doesn't support sub-second resolution on Windows,
# so do what it does using only R code.
ep <- c(0,which(diff(.index(ex)%/%0.1%/%1+1) != 0),NROW(ex))
x <- period.apply(ex, ep, colSums, na.rm=TRUE)
x <- align.time(x, 0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't follow why it wouldn't be sufficient to just drop all but the last in a sequence of repeated timestamps.  make.index.unique seems like exactly what I want to do, just the output is not what I'm expecting.  You can see from the two head(data) calls that a few entries of 2013-04-16 00:00:02.5 were deleted, but not 2013-04-16 00:01:09.7.  I tried subtracting one of the 2013-04-16 00:01:09.7 from the other and it returned -0.0999999 secs, so somehow internally my indices aren't truncated the way they're displayed, even after align.time(data, n = 0.1).

Comment: @tmakino: well, your "Actual" object only contained 6 rows, so I could not replicate the problem... hence the repeated requests for a reproducible example. It's very difficult for people to help you if they cannot replicate the problem you need help with.

Comment: I understand, and I've also failed repeatedly to produce an example that behaves consistently with my data.  I will keep trying, but if you can provide any hints please let me know.

Comment: @tmakino: I honestly don't know and I don't have time to imagine situations that might cause the problem you describe.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway for taking the time to edit my question.  I'll post any updates but I'll try to find a way to do this without using align.time with fractional seconds.